# How to resize a polygon (rectangle or circle) in Qgis?

Tags: qgis

Yes I used the Rectangles Ovals plugin to create a rectangle then rotate it and move it nto position. But if you want to resize it that is where the fun starts because it is just a polygon with four corners, you can move them all independently so it is very hard to keep proportion or angles correct.

A rectangle is four lines at right angles. To make it longer or wider you just need to be able  to increase the length of two of the sides. A circle has many more "sides" so this would be harder to implement using measurements alone, but it could be done this way.

I don't know if anyone has implemented a plugin that can do this resizing. I just know dragging the nodes to new positions is very tedious especially trying to keep a circle circular. Something that let me lengthen the individual sides is a quick-and-dirty way of increasing a polygon but there may be some better option. But the Rectangles and Ovals plugin only lets me draw new ones and if the new one is the wrong size I have to start again.

Comment: Can you use this answer http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63000/how-to-resize-shapefile-features-proportionally-in-qgis

Comment: I think that answer depends on the QGSAffine plugin which is no longer available or working.

Comment: Why are you unable to define the correct size of the rectangle or circle when you create it initially?  If you know where the polygons must be and how big they should be, then the Rectangles-Ovals plugin is all you need, so it seems to me that you need to focus more on your initial preparation/measurement rather than on trying to tweak the result (which will never be as satisfactory).  Can you edit your question to include details on how you are defining the sizes and positions of your polygons.

Comment: If you are able to run a python script I can provide you with some code that you can run to create regular shapes around a central point. You can supply the centre coordinates and type a number of corners you want your shape to have, and specify the radius. It allows you to choose the number of degrees rotation. I have found it quite useful at times. It is independant of GIS software though, (will work with almost any map software) does your question really require a QGIS specific solution?