# scale polygon in Qgis

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-plugins, scale

The task is to scale a polygon in QGIS.
The procedure is performed tracing the polygon and then apply a scaling factor ( the factor used is " Distance on the ground" / " Distance on map " ) .

Both ArcGIS and AutoCAD there is the "scale" tool.

Is there any way to do Qgis or plugin?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63000/how-to-resize-shapefile-features-proportionally-in-qgis