# GRASS v.transform tool producing no results QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon

I'm working on a simple polygon feature representing the Western Cape province of South Africa. My goal is to enlarge the polygon so it can stand out from the others.

To do so I've used the v.transform tool, but the output layer is empty. The picture below shows how I've computed the tool, I might be doing something wrong.
[image]

As I understand it:

X shift: I've put the x coordinate of the centroid of the polygon.

Y shift: same for the y coordinate

X scale: the factor by which I'd like to enlarge my polygon (I've used 130% for the example, according to another post: [How to resize shapefile features proportionally in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63000/how-to-resize-shapefile-features-proportionally-in-qgis))

GRASS GIS 7 region: my canvas extent.

Comment: Shift = move somewhere else. Also, I do not know, whether shift and extent may be based on different units.

Comment: The only issue is that I do not how to do this on a shapefile with multiple polygons

Answer (score 1):

I found a way. I shifted from using the GRASS tool to the SAGA tool "transform vector layer". The wizard is simpler and easily computable:

[image]

dX: I left the default O

dY: same

Angle: 0

Scale factor X: factor by which you want to enlarge it: 1,3 will enlarge by 130%

Scale factor Y: same

X: centroid X of polygon

Y: same for Y

Comment: You mixed the fields!
dX - your X coordinates
dY - your Y coordinates

X - left 0
Y - left 0